# Are there symbols for referencing non-section entities?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, chapters

The `\S` symbol is often to reference numbered sections or sub-sections.

But - what about referencing *chapters* (numbered or otherwise)? Or paragraphs, or appendices, or other entities for that matter? Are there additional symbols usable for such references? If not, it makes sections kind of "over-privileged" entities.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Right you are.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there is nothing else corresponding to the `\S` glyph. Don't take "section" or "sub-section" to refer to LaTeX's `\section` and `\subsection`. Consider `\S` to simply refer to a numbered portion of a document. In other contexts people may be thinking of portions called "rule" or for ISO International Standards "clause" is used. In other contexts "head" and "subhead" etc are used. `\S` could be used to refer to any of these.